# Can not get python file output using node.js

Tags: python, node.js

I am trying to fetch python output from Node.js script using postman but unable to get the required output. I am explaining my code below.

> app.js:

```
router.post('/usecase-workflow', async (req, res) => {

  try{
    let responseUsecase = await usecaseWorkflow.fetchUsecaseWorkflow(req);
    res.send(responseUsecase);
  }catch(error) {
    responseObj = {
      status: 'error',
      msg: 'Error occurred while downloading ubot file',
      body: error
    }
    res.send(responseObj);
  }
})
```

> usecaseWorkflow.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const axios = require('axios');
const request = require('request');


class DefineUseCase {

    fetchUsecaseWorkflow = async(req) => {
        try{
            const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5005/usecase-workflow',req);
            //console.log(response);
            return response;
        }catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}

module.exports = new DefineUseCase();
```

When I am doing REST API call from postman the above code is executing. I am giving the screen shot of postman below.

[image]

Here my need is i will upload one zip file and one node.js REST API will call. Inside the node script I am calling one python file to get the final output. But as per my code its not giving any result. If I am calling the Python file directly from postman Its giving some result. I am also giving python call postman screen shot below.

[image]

So here I need to fetch the same above output via node.js REST API.

Comment: There are many things which seem wrong here:
1. Where are you passing the file from node.js to python server?
2. You are catching all the errors in `usecaseWorkflow` and not returning anything to the index.js where you have another try/catch which therefore is not being used correctly

Comment: You can check both screenshot of postman. I am doing direct call to python server and got the desired output. But if you will check my 1st screen shot here first called the node rest api and then python server call. For both case the input is same. Any way if possible can you please make this workable.

Comment: I don't think you are passing the file through axios correctly. Can you point out how the file is being passed from axios to python server?

Comment: @tbking: 1- I selected the file in postman and called one REST API to node script. 2- from node script i want to send that file to python script using axios. 3- In python side I have the code like `request.files.getlist("file")` to get the required file for execution but the python script is unable catch the same file.

Comment: Here my concern is same python API is working fine from postman but If I am calling that API using axios with same req object its not working.